# Determining some vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I'm having a very difficult time with this problem.

The mast $CD$ is kept in balance by two wires which form the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with the horizontal plane. The length of the vector $F_1$ in the wire $AC$ is $P$. The sum of the vectors $F_1 + F_2 = F$ is vertical. Determine the vectors in the wire $CB$ and $F$ respectively.

[image: Problem fig. 1.1]

Thanks!

Comment: A force has no length, it has an amplitude or a norm.

Comment: Sorry, changed it to vectors.

Comment: Welcome on the stackexchange. Before aksing a question, you should try to solve it. What did you try ? What point presents a difficulty ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $CA=b$, $CB=a$.  We're looking for numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $(xa+yb)\perp (b-a)$.  From $\langle ax+by,b-a\rangle=0$ you'll be able to determine $x/y$.